# Existence of rectifiable/piecewise $C^1$ curves between two points of an open connected domain in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, curves, connectedness, path-connected

The question is the same as the title. Precisely,

> Suppose $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ is an open connected domain. Given two points $z_0, z_1 \in \Omega$, does there exist a rectifiable curve $\gamma : [0, 1] \to \Omega$ with $\gamma(0) = z_0, \gamma(1) = z_1$. What about piecewise $C^1$ $\gamma$ ?

Since $\mathbb{C}$ is locally path connected and $\Omega$ is connected, we have that $\Omega$ is path connected, so that there is a *continuous* curve $\gamma$ which starts at $z_0$ and ends at $z_1$. But can we always choose $\gamma$ to be rectifiable or piecewise $C^1$ (the latter would imply the former though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we can. Take some continuous curve $C$ connecting the two points. Choose some open covering $\mathcal U$ of the curve by discs whose center is on the curve and which are contained in $\Omega$. Since the curve is the continuous image of a compact interval, it is itself compact, and thus there exists a finite subcovering of the curve by discs centered on the curve. For simplicity, add two additional discs, one centered at the start point, one at the end point.

Now connect the centers of intersecting discs by straight lines. You get a connected graph whose (finite number of) edges are contained in $\Omega$, and connect start and end point. Now just choose any path from the start to end point along these edges.

To be completely rigorous, you need to fill in some blanks, though: Why can we choose $\mathcal U$ as desired? Why is the graph connected? Why are the edges contained in $\Omega$?

Comment: The graph is connected because if you order the $t$ values for the finitely many centers of the  finite cover and remove discs which are subsets of other discs, you get that if two consecutive ones don't intersect, then you miss out a point in between. Also the line joining the center of two intersecting open discs lies in their union. 

So you end up proving the stronger result that the two points can be connected by a piecewise _linear_ $\gamma$. Is that correct?

Comment: You have to be a bit more careful with the ordering. The centers may be orderable by where they lie on the curve, but consecutive ones may not intersect. For instance, on a straight line of length 3, you could have three discs, one of radius 2 at the beginning, one of radius 1/2 somewhere in the middle and another one of radius 3 at the end such that the two discs at the sides intersect, but the middle one only intersects one of the two others, not both.

Comment: I see. Suppose the graph is not connected. Then the set of discs can be divided into two sets such that there is no "edge" between these sets. Consider $A, B$ to be the union of the discs in the two sets (so $A$ and $B$ are open). Then $A \cap B = \varnothing$. But $A \cup B \supseteq \gamma([0, 1])$ which is connected. This is impossible by definition of connectness.